# Is that a problem with plugins versions? Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

after using "vue create" command I get these versions in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
```

Is that normal?

Here are the versions in vue ui:
[imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SGfk.jpg)

@vue-cli latest version installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just normal, basically $sudo vue create generates latest version available
which in this case is 4.5.15, talking about the stable release it must be somewhere around 2.6.14

#vue.js #vuejs3